Wheel (?) rattling/scrapping/vibrating until I let off gas
F-150 has suddenly developed a rattling that sounds like it's coming from the front right wheel. It is very "tinny" or aluminum sounding, and ONLY occurs during acceleration. As soon as I let off the gas pedal it stops and only resumes when the vehicle is in motion. Shop said there was a loose heat shield and supposedly removed it, but the sound persists. Any thoughts before I take it back?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest two things: 1) don't drive it until you figure it out; 2) they took the wrong heat shield off.

Thanks! The fact that the noise stops when I let off the gas is what I can't make sense of. How would they correspond to it being a heat shield?

The engine is under load, which will cause more/different vibration during acceleration. A heat shield is a likely issue with the scenario you've laid out.

Your Muffler could be the problem. I had exact same kind of rattle in my chevy only let up when I’d let up off the gas or until I got really moving. Could not place that it was coming from the back unless I had everything cleared out of the back and then it got really bad.
Okay I’d check your muffler.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
